# Login pelo Facebook sem o aplicativo instalado

Tags: android, facebook

Tenho um app com um botão de login pro facebook. Pra integração, segui esses passos no [quickstart de android](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts) no site de developers do facebook. Bem no começo ele diz:

> Facebook SDK for Android uses Facebook to support Login and Sharing. If you develop or test with a real device, install Facebook from Google Play.

Dizendo que tenho que instalar o app pra usar a funcionalidade de login. Já fiz a integração direito seguindo os passos que o quickstart dá. Mas no meu celular que estou usando pra debuggar o app, quando clico no botão de login dá falha, tenho um textView que mostra o erro:

```
Login attempt failed
```

Mas eu já utilizei apps de terceiros que tem essa funcionalidade de login com conta do facebook mas funciona no meu celular (o visual não é o mesmo, ele faz como se fosse pelo navegador), sendo que não tenho o app do facebook.

Minha pergunta é: **Como posso fazer login pelo facebook funcionar no meu app, mesmo que o usuário não tenha o aplicativo do facebook instalado?**

*OBS: Estou usando a última versão da SDK - 2.4.*

**UPDATE:**

A [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#dialogs) fala que se o aplicativo do facebook estiver instalado, a dialog nativa será exibida; se não tiver instalado, será exibida uma dialog não nativa num webview.

Agora fiquei mais curioso pra saber por que ao clicar no botão ele não exibe a dialog de login. Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É meio embaraçoso, mas acabei colocando a permissão de internet no lugar errado, coloquei dentro da minha MainActivity em vez de fora, dentro da application:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>
```

Agora o dialog do webview aparece normal, mesmo sem o app do facebook. Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Para usar o login sem o aplicativo do Facebook instalado, você tem que adicionar no seu AndroidManifest uma Acitivity, segue o código:

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Vou mostrar como eu fiz o meu.
1- Crie um App no Facebook Develope e adicione no gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
```

2- Adicione ao seu AndroidManifest dentro da tag application

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>



    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>
```

3- Crie uma Class que vai extends de Application, segue:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    printKeyHash();
    //FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); // para iniciar o FacebookSDK
}
public void printKeyHash() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.examplo.blabla", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("TAG", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
}
```

3.1- Na minha class tem o metodo para exibir sua KeyHash que voce precisa configurar no Facebook Develope
3.2 feito isso comente ou apague pois voce nao vai precisar mais.
3.3 - Descomente o FacebookSdk para iniciar em sua aplicação ("Não esqueça")
4- Criei um layout onde vai ter um botao e um textView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="192dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

5- E um Fragment que vai conter:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView mTextDetails;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess");
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onError " + e);
    }
};


public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setupTokenTracker();
    setupProfileTracker();

    mTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setupTextDetails(view);
    setupLoginButton(view);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void setupTextDetails(View view) {
    mTextDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
}


private void setupTokenTracker() {
    mTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            Log.d("TAG", "" + currentAccessToken);
        }
    };
}

private void setupProfileTracker() {
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            Log.d("TAG", "" + currentProfile);
            mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(currentProfile));
        }
    };
}

private void setupLoginButton(View view) {
    LoginButton mButtonLogin = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mButtonLogin.setFragment(this);
    mButtonLogin.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    mButtonLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);
}

private String constructWelcomeMessage(Profile profile) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (profile != null) {
        stringBuffer.append("Bem - vindo " + profile.getName());
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

}
```

6- Faça com que sua MainActivity chame o Fragment.

6.1 - O usuário vai clicar no botão de login feito isso vai ser mostrado no textView uma mensagem de boas vindas com seu nome.

Comment: Sou grato por sua vontade em ajudar, mas o meu código estava quase igual o seu, com a diferença que não estou usando ```Fragment```. Acabei descobrindo que coloquei a permissão de internet no lugar errado. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.